# Technical term for the border that appears around the screen, usually in response to low health?

Tags: gui, terminology

This had a strange term but I can't remember what it's called and it's difficult to search for.

Comment: Is it called Red Haze perhaps? https://forum.unity.com/threads/adding-red-haze-around-camera-when-health-is-low.44687/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't think there's actually a well-accepted common term for this.

Comment: @Almo that seems to me to be a reason to answer "there isn't one" - ideally citing conflicting examples to demonstrate the lack of consensus - rather than a reason to close the question.

Answer (score 5):

At our studio (Ubisoft Toronto) we usually call it a (low) health vignette.

A vignette in photography & film refers to an effect around the edges of the frame (usually a darkening or defocus) like this:

[image: Example of a darkening vignette]

By attaching modifiers to it like "low health" or "super" etc. we express "that effect at the edges of your screen when you're in the ______ state"

Here are some sources that also call it a health vignette:

- [Low Health Vignette Effect - #17 Creating A SideScroller With Unreal Engine 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmaOjS4p7o4)
- [HOW TO ADD A RED HEALTH VIGNETTE/TINT IN YOUR SCREEN IN VANILLA MINECRAFT 1.11/1.12?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MePG2_9835w)

If it's particularly intrusive into the middle of the frame, we call it "strawberry jam" ;)

Comment: Vignette is 1000% exactly the word I wanted. As far as it not being a well-accepted term, I disagree. I believe this to be the correct term, not just due to its frequency of use, but its grounding as a more generic term (e.g. in photography). Many terms used in specific fields are derived from the related fields that precede them (like "vignette" in photography, as mentioned).